# Virtual Box: Port of machine not accessible

Tags: networking, virtualbox, port, bridge

i have a linux VM running in my windows 10 machine.
The network of the VM is configured as a bridge in virtual box.
I can access ports 80,443 und 22 from everywhere.
But some ports (e.g. 5222) have a service listening, but i can't connect to them (connection refused).

When i run a telnet 5222 from the machine itself i get a connection using both "localhost" and the ip of the machine.

The VM itself is a hipchat-server, a preconfigured OVA image provided by Atlassian.
It is running Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a firewall blocking the higher ports. Check both the firewall configuration in your Windows 10 machine and in the Linux guest, if any (iptables, firewalld, ufw, etc.) and open connections from outside to port 5222.

Comment: I am having this only with new virtualbox versions. Really causing a big problem for me.